# Is changed items from array go to Garbage Collection?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, clr

I have two classes which second inherit by first.

then I have this:

```
First[] tab = new First[5];
tab[0] = new First();
tab[1] = new First();
tab[2] = new First();
```

and my question is: If I make this:

```
tab[1] = new Second();
```

what's happened whitch memory which I use to invoke tab[1] in first time? It's go to Garbage Collection and memory is free?

If not what can I do to free it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing an object from an array causes that object to no longer be referenced by the array.

Like any other object, it will eventually be garbage collected if no other rooted objects are referencing it.

Comment: It can be GC'd just fine if there are references to it, objects are eligible for GC when they are *unreachable*. You can have a hundred references (including cycles) to it, of none of those references can be used by the application, it's garbage. And of course weak references (even if they're in use) don't prevent GC either.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute

```
tab[1] = new Second();
```

The instance of `First` that used to be in `tab[1]` is no longer referenced, and is marked for garbage collection.

The memory itself isn't actually made available again until the garbage collector runs, which is not immediate.

That of course assumes that nothing else is referencing that instance.

There is a *lot* of great articles out there on the .NET garbage collector and exactly how it works, if you Google it.

Answer (score 1):

tab[1]'s "First" Should go to garbage collection (eventually) as no other variable points to that memory.

Answer (score 0):

In addition you can force an immediate garbage collection by `System.GC.Collect()`

Comment: `GC.Collect` is an advanced feature that should only be used in very special circumstances. Knowledge of its existence should not be given to someone who is only just coming to terms with the concept of garbage collection.